# Build is successful but the runtime dependency seems bad in Gradle dependency

Tags: java, maven, gradle

```
dependencies {
 compile 'org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.13'
    compile group: 'org.apache.commons', name: 'commons-math3' , version: '+'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Even if I add this, when I run *gradle build*, it works, and codes with commons-math3 can be compiled. But when I run a jar file in build/,

it says *Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/math3/complex/Complex*

But the official Gradle site says, the resource in 'compile' will also be included in 'runtime' dependency. and I also tried adding the *commons-math* to runtime. but it does not work.

Maybe this is my misunderstood of the dependency system.

How can I include external library from maven repository into a jar file made by the Gradle.

Comment: how do you run the jar? In particular, how did you set the class path?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are looking for is either the distribution zips produced by the `application` plugin or the shadow jar (also called fat jar) produced by the `shadowJar` plugin:

## The distribution zip (`application` plugin)

### About the distribution zip

The distribution zips look like this:

```
my-app-0.2.0.zip
├──bin
│  ├──my-app
│  └──my-app.bat
└──lib
   ├──my-app-0.2.0.jar
   ├──slf4j-api.1.7.13.jar
   └──commons-math3-3.6.jar
```

You can then run your application with its dependencies by unzipping what has been produced in `build/distributions/` and running either `my-app.bat` (on windows) or `./my-app` (on linux or OS X)

### Building a distribution zip

Here is a sample gradle build file for making a distribution zip:

`build.gradle`

```groovy
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'application'

mainClassName = 'org.myapp.Main'

repositories { jcenter() }
dependencies {
    compile 'org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.13'
    compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-math3:3.6'

    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Can be run with `gradle distributionZip` or `gradle distributionTar`. To just run the application, use `gradle run`.

## The shadow jar

### About the shadow jar

The shadow jar is one giant jar file that is a combination of your program and its libraries, packed together into one file. You will get a file that is self-contained and can be run by a double-click on most systems (e.g. on Windows that works, on Xubuntu it can be run by right-clicking and selecting 'Run with Oracle Java 8 Runtime', etc...).

### Building a distribution zip

Here is, again, a sample `build.gradle` file:

```groovy
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'com.github.johnrengelman.shadow'

mainClassName = 'org.myapp.Main'

jar {
    manifest {
        attributes('Main-Class': mainClassName)
    }
}

buildscript {
    repositories { jcenter() }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.github.jengelman.gradle.plugins:shadow:1.2.2'
    }
}

repositories { jcenter() }
dependencies {
    compile 'org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.13'
    compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-math3:3.6'

    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Run it with `gradle shadowJar` - Your jar with packed dependencies will be in `build/libs` and it will be named `my-app-x.x.x-all.jar`.

Answer (score 1):

Gradle is first of all a build tool (just like maven, btw). 
Its "responisiblity" starts when you feed it a source file and ends when you get your artifact (in your case its a jar).

Now when you're going to actually run your application there is a plethora of different options here.
If you just run `java -jar <your_jar>` you are responsible by yourself to construct the classpath.
If you run it with some kind of external runner, you should read the documentation of it and supply it a classpath.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you I added  from configurations.compile.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it)  into 'jar'